# Best way to check if a field has a particular custom attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, field, custom-attributes

What is the best way to check if a field has a particular custom attribute?

My current approach is like so, but it seems a little redundant:

```
foreach (FieldInfo fi in typeof(ClassName).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    if (fi.GetCustomAttribute<AttributeName>() is AttributeName)
    {
        Debug.Log($"my GetCustomAttribute check was true for {fi.Name}.");
    }
}
```

Comment: `typeof(ClassName).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Where(fi=>fi.GetCustomAttribute<AttributeName>() != null)`

Comment: Cool, I hadn't thought to use the null check.